# send audio to raspberry pi over wifi

Tags: audio, wifi, raspberry-pi3

I am just starting to work with raspberry pi 3. I want to be able to send short audio clips (a few seconds long) from my computer to the raspberry pi and play them on it.

Can you point me to recent tutorials which you know are working? Or any tips for libraries I can use? Literally anything to get started on this.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't think that so would be a good choice for this kind of questions but here is what you need, Try to google them with your preferred programming language:

1. Socket programming in raspberry pi
2. Send file over TCP (or maybe UDP in your case) in socket programming
3. Play audio in raspberry pi